# OAuth Authentication using Httr

Tags: r, httr

I am reading this tutorial

https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth2-github.r

I wrote this code

```
library(httr)
library(httpuv)
client_secret <- "9821663e0c51b4531ea0ef62224ab78a1xxxxxxxxx"
client_id <- "62d0280a5824b2a6393b"
github.app <- oauth_app("github", client_id, client_secret)
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), github.app)
```

Upon executing the last line above,  my RStudio session crashes with the error message

```
adding .httr-oauth to .gitignore 
waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Error in withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(evalq((function (hash=(TRUE)
parent = parent.frame, : object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found
```

[image]

[image]

It also opens the browser where it goes to `http://localhost:1410/?code=7abea00044ed4529659c&state=tgQDIm9up1` and says page not found

Comment: I'd start by reinstalling httpuv and Rcpp